# DateTime object not returning correct timezone

Tags: php

DateTime object and date() method returning incorrect time.

php timezone already set in php.ini getter methods verify timezone settings. but generated time showing 4 hours behind

PHP Version 5.4.16

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: '. date_default_timezone_get() .'<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone') . "<br>";
}

$d = new DateTime();
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "<br>";
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Istanbul'));
echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

results:

```
date_default_timezone_set: Europe/Istanbul
date.timezone: Europe/Istanbul
2016-12-03 10:44:15
2016-12-03 10:44:15
```

It should be 2016-12-03 14:44:15

Comment: date_default_timezone_set(Europe/Istanbul); use it.

Comment: Show us the output for `$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')); echo $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: Did you check your system datetime? run date command in shell?

Comment: UTC output is 6 hours behind. system date same as php "Sat Dec  3 11:23:10 EET 2016". but doesn't matter. I want to set php timezone not system date.

Comment: PHP scripts reads server's datetime. So your system needs to have the correct time with its timezone. Your EET time output doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

use this simple code

echo  date("d-M-Y");

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/calcutta');

echo date("h:i:sa");

Comment: date_default_timezone_get() already returning correct value. the problem is created date doesn't match with timezone. so Asia/calcutta timezone returning same as Europe/Istanbul